# netty pipeline order for outbound message

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty v4.1.9final and trying to send a message from client to server. I tried setting up the channel client initializer with the handler as follows on the client side:

```
final Bootstrap bootstrap = BootstrapGenerator.generate();
bootstrap.handler(new XmlClientInitializer());
```

**XMLClientInitializer**

```
public class XmlClientInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        final ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

        pipeline.addLast("fileEncoder", new FileEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("handler", new XmlSenderHandler());
    }
}
```

**FileEncoder**

```
public class FileEncoder extends MessageToByteEncoder<String> {
```

**XmlSenderHandler**

```
public class XmlSenderHandler extends ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(XmlSenderHandler.class.getName());
    private static ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) {
        log.info("attempting to write messages to server {}", msg.toString());
        ctx.write(msg, promise);
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("FutureReturnValueIgnored")
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        super.exceptionCaught(ctx, cause);
    }
}
```

Even though the FileEncoder is defined first in the pipeline, it gets called after the xml handler (which is not what I am seeking).  Is this because the FileEncoder is extending MessageToByteEncoder or am I configuring the channel incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the pipeline is configured correctly. The point is that the inbound event is processed from the first handler to the last, and the outbound event is processed from the last handler to the first one.
[ChannelPipeline doc](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html)